# Flutter Riverpod StateNotifierProvider: only watch changes for part of a model

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a model like this:

```dart
class TimerModel {
  const TimerModel(this.timeLeft, this.buttonState);
  final String timeLeft;
  final ButtonState buttonState;
}

enum ButtonState {
  initial,
  started,
  paused,
  finished,
}
```

And here is the StateNotifierProvider:

```dart
class TimerNotifier extends StateNotifier<TimerModel> {
  TimerNotifier() : super(_initialState);

  static const int _initialDuration = 10;
  static final _initialState = TimerModel(
    _durationString(_initialDuration),
    ButtonState.initial,
  );

  final Ticker _ticker = Ticker();
  StreamSubscription<int> _tickerSubscription;

  void start() {
    if (state.buttonState == ButtonState.paused) {
      _tickerSubscription?.resume();
      state = TimerModel(state.timeLeft, ButtonState.started);
    } else {
      _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
      _tickerSubscription =
          _ticker.tick(ticks: _initialDuration).listen((duration) {
        state = TimerModel(_durationString(duration), ButtonState.started);
      });
      _tickerSubscription.onDone(() { 
        state = TimerModel(state.timeLeft, ButtonState.finished);
      });
      state =
          TimerModel(_durationString(_initialDuration), ButtonState.started);
    }
  }

  static String _durationString(int duration) {
    final String minutesStr =
        ((duration / 60) % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final String secondsStr =
        (duration % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$minutesStr:$secondsStr';
  }

  void pause() {
    _tickerSubscription?.pause();
    state = TimerModel(state.timeLeft, ButtonState.paused);
  }

  void reset() {
    _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
    state = _initialState;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tickerSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class Ticker {
  Stream<int> tick({int ticks}) {
    return Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (x) => ticks - x - 1)
        .take(ticks);
  }
}
```

I can listen for all changes in state like this:

```dart
final timerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TimerNotifier>((ref) => TimerNotifier());
```

However I want to make another provider that only listens for changes in the ButtonState. This doesn't work:

```dart
final buttonProvider = StateProvider<ButtonState>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(timerProvider.state).buttonState;
});
```

because it still returns all the state changes.

This also doesn't work:

```dart
final buttonProvider = StateProvider<ButtonState>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(timerProvider.state.buttonState);
});
```

Because the `state` object doesn't have a `buttonState` property.

How do I only watch buttonState changes?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible. My recommendation would be to make your StateNotifier<TimerModel> a StateNotifier<ButtonState> and just keep track of the time remaining in the StateNotifier (outside of state), as it doesn't seem you are accepting a time parameter anyway.

Comment: @AlexHartford, I found a solution (see below), but I'm also thinking of doing something like what you suggested as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `watch` gives a new state whenever the watched state changes. So can solve the problem in two parts like so:

```dart
final _buttonState = Provider<ButtonState>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(timerProvider.state).buttonState;
});
```

Using this provider will cause a rebuild every time the `timerProvider.state` changes. However, the trick is to do the following:

```dart
final buttonProvider = Provider<ButtonState>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(_buttonState);
});
```

Since `_buttonState` will be the same for most of the `timerProvider.state` changes, watching `_buttonState` will only cause rebuilds when `_buttonState` actually changes.

Thanks to [this post](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/158#issuecomment-699638027) for showing the answer. That post also indicates that there will be a simplified syntax soon:

```dart
final buttonState = ref.watch(timerProvider.state.select((state) => state.buttonState));
```

Comment: Awesome, yeah that makes sense. Glad you got it sorted!